# PHPExcel not filling up rows

Tags: php, phpexcel

This is my code using PHPExcel and NinjaForms. Basically the code does go inside `if( isset($sub[$field_key]) ){` so all data is OK. I have also echoed it but somehow the rows are empty.

```
public function export_file( $form_id ) {

            // set xls always on
        $use_xls = true;

            // set save dir
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
            $tmp_file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/test/' . $form_id . '/form-submissions-'. $form_id .'.xls';;

        $sub_results = $this->get_submissions( $form_id );

        $num_submissions = $this->count_submissions($form_id );

        $fields_meta = Ninja_Forms()->form($form_id)->get_fields();

        $field_names=array();
        $header_row=array();
        $header_row['id'] = __('ID','ninja-forms-spreadsheet');
        $header_row['date_submitted'] = __('Submission date','ninja-forms-spreadsheet');

        foreach($fields_meta as $field_id => $field){
            $field_settings = $field->get_settings();

                    // skip save fields
                    if( $field_settings['type'] == 'save' || $field_settings['type'] == 'submit' ) {
                        unset( $fields_meta[$field_id] );
                        continue;
                    }

            $field_names[$field_id] = sanitize_title( $field_settings['label'].'-'.$field_id );
            $field_types[$field_id] = $field_settings['type'];
                    $header_row[$field_id] = $field_settings['label'];
            }

            //die();

        require_once( plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ).'/ninja-forms-excel-export/includes/PHPExcel.php');
      $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
      $row_number = 1;

        // this should be the same wordpress uses and therefore be the saver choice
        PHPExcel_Shared_File::setUseUploadTempDirectory( true );

        // Table Headline
      $col_index = 0;
      foreach ($header_row as $headline) {
        $col = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex( $col_index );
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($col.$row_number)->setValue( $headline );
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($col.$row_number)->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $col_index++;
      }
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePane( "A2" );
        $row_number++;

            /*
             * Loop over each sub
             */
            foreach($sub_results as $sub){      

                    $col = 'A';
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($col++.$row_number)->setValueExplicit( $sub['_seq_num'], PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC );
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($col++.$row_number)->setValueExplicit( $sub['date_submitted'] );

                    $col_index = 0;                 
                    foreach ($fields_meta as $field_id => $field) {
                $field_key = '_field_'.$field_id;

                if( isset($sub[$field_key]) ){

                                    $field_value = $sub[$field_key];
                    $col = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex( 2+$col_index );
                    $field_value = maybe_unserialize( $field_value );

                    echo $field_types[$field_id] . ' ';

                    if( in_array($field_types[$field_id], array( 'shipping', 'total', 'number' ) ) ){ // float values
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($col.$row_number) ->setValueExplicit( $field_value, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC );
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($col.$row_number)
                            ->getNumberFormat()
                            ->setFormatCode('#,##');
                    }elseif( in_array($field_types[$field_id], array( 'starrating', 'quantity' ) ) ){ // integer values
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($col.$row_number) ->setValueExplicit( $field_value, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC );
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($col.$row_number)
                            ->getNumberFormat()
                            ->setFormatCode('#');
                    }elseif( in_array($field_types[$field_id], array( 'checkbox' ) ) || strpos($field_types[$field_id], '-optin') ){
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($col.$row_number)->setValueExplicit( $field_value, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING );
                    }elseif( in_array($field_types[$field_id], array( 'listcheckbox' ) ) ){
                        $field_output = $field_value;
                        if( is_array($field_value) ){
                            $field_output = '';
                            foreach ($field_value as $key => $value) {
                                if( $field_output == '' )
                                    $field_output = $value;
                                else
                                    $field_output .= ', ' . $value;
                            }
                        }
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($col.$row_number)->setValueExplicit( htmlspecialchars_decode ( $field_output,ENT_QUOTES ), PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING );
                    }elseif( $field_types[$field_id] == 'file_upload' ){
                        if( is_array($field_value)){
                            $field_value = implode("\n", $field_value);
                        }

                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($col.$row_number)->setValueExplicit( htmlspecialchars_decode ( $field_value,ENT_QUOTES ), PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING );
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($col.$row_number)
                            ->getAlignment()
                            ->setWrapText(true);
                    }elseif( $field_types[$field_id] == 'textarea' ){
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($col.$row_number)->setValueExplicit( htmlspecialchars_decode ( $field_value,ENT_QUOTES ), PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING );
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($col.$row_number)
                            ->getAlignment()
                            ->setWrapText(true);
                    }else{
                        if( is_array($field_value) ){
                            $field_value = implode('; ', $field_value);
                        }
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($col.$row_number)->setValueExplicit( htmlspecialchars_decode ( $field_value,ENT_QUOTES ), PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING );
                    }

                }
                        $col_index++;
            }
            $row_number++;
        }

        $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($objPHPExcel);
        ob_end_clean();
        $objWriter->save($tmp_file);

    }
```

The excel modified time is updated correctly but all rows are empty except the first header row in bold. I am not sure what is the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use XLSXReader library its much better and stable compare to PHPExcel.
https://github.com/gneustaetter/XLSXReader

Comment: I want to use PHPExcel for now as it is not viable to start converting everything. Thanks.